# CollectionViewCell not showing

Tags: storyboard, uicollectionviewcell, xib, collectionview

[image]

I am developing an application in Swift language. When a storyboard is used in the videos I watch on the internet, it comes with a `CollectionViewCell` and `ContentView` as above. But when I create a `xib` file with `cocoutouch` and do the same operation, nothing appears in it and I cannot add it.

Can someone who knows the reason help?